# upcase array that has both strings and numbers

Tags: ruby, arrays, string-formatting

I am comparing large arrays to find missing elements. But one array will all be capitalized and the other is not. So I want to format the one array but am having issues. This is an example of the array I am trying to format.

```
array = [ 023, "Bac001", "abc123"]
```

Then I try to capitalize everything

```
array.map!(&:upcase)
```

but get undefined method 'upcase' for 023

is there a way around this?

Comment: You're trying to upcase a number. Isn't it supposed to be a string?

Comment: What kind of number is `023`?

Comment: I am working with skus, and filtering out bad sku formats. I don't understand why this question got down voted?

Comment: You haven't made the question clear. What do you want in the output for the element corresponding to `023`? Do you want `"023"`, `023` (which is `19`), or something else? Can't you realize until you are told that the question is unclear?

Comment: I just wanted to capitalize the letters in an array. People answered my question nicely. I appreciate the help. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array.map! { |s| s.kind_of?(String) ? s.upcase : s }
```

This will not attempt to upcase any non-string element of the array. So it will work on arrays like:

```
array = [23, 1.27, "Bac001", "abc123", {:foo => 3}]
```

Yielding:

```
[23, 1.27, "BAC001", "ABC123", {:foo => 3}]
```

Comment: While *close*, checking classes is going to miss out on a lot of opportunities.

Comment: @tadman it will work with any subclass of `String`. I suppose if you defined another class, not a subclass, that had an `upcase` method it would not convert it. Quite the corner case, but sure.

Comment: Example: `Symbol`. It's not a string, but it supports `upcase`.

Comment: @tadman It doesn't work (no method `upcase` for Symbol) for Ruby version < 1.9. But I understand your point.

Comment: In that case, Symbol doesn't `respond_to?` the method, so it's fine. Additionally Ruby 1.8 is [end-of-lifed](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/) so those concerns are largely irrelevant. I think Stefan's answer is the best here. It works for a wider number of cases without issues like this.

Comment: @tadman, I do understand that `respond_to?` is the most flexible. However, the OP didn't express whether they wanted it to work for a wider number of cases or not (having mentioned only "Strings" and "numbers"), so it's somewhat academic. I could just as easily imagine a case where one might not want it to work that way. So "best" is relative to what one believes the requirements are. For the record, I rather like Stefan's response the most as well.

Comment: @mbratch not only flexible. `s.kind_of?(Symbol) ? s.upcase : s` would raise an exception in Ruby 1.8 whereas `respond_to?` would not.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use [`Object#respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F):

```
def upcase_elements(ary)
  ary.map { |e| e.respond_to?(:upcase) ? e.upcase : e }
end

upcase_elements([23, "BAC001", "ABC123"])
#=> [23, "BAC001", "ABC123"]
```

Checking if the receiver responds to a method is more flexible than checking its type:

```
upcase_elements([:foo, "bar"])
#=> [:FOO, "BAR"]
```

Comment: This is the proper duck-typed way of doing this.